# Trajectory of kicked ball

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, projectile-motion

A ball is kicked from the ground with a vertical velocity of $10 m/s$; how long does it take the ball to reach maximum height above ground?

I used equation $v=u+at$ but rearranged it and used the $9.8$ as there was nothing else given. Is the answer 1.026?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Britt Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct indeed

- $v=v_0-gt=0 \implies t=\frac{v_0}{g}$

and the maximum height is

- $h=v_0 t-\frac12gt^2=\frac{v_0^2}{g}-\frac12g\frac{v_0^2}{g^2}=\frac12\frac{v_0^2}{g}$